# Panel interview: Should I bring up salary if they don't?

Tags: interviewing, salary, negotiation

Soon I'm having only the 2nd panel interview I've ever done (and only 3rd final interview I've ever done). They emailed the salary range when they sent me the location, day, time.

Salary range is low, 53-60k, my salary range would be 60-65k. This is for an IT/contracts manager job, for which I'm well qualified with 15+ years' IT sysadmin experience.

If they don't bring up salary, should I bring it up?

Methinks **not** since too many people there, **but** *seeking additional ideas, opinions*.

If they **do** bring up salary I will respond as below.

If they offer me the job I think they may do it via phone and they may make a specific offer or they may ask me, in which case it's sort of easier to discuss with just one person.

Comment: One reason not to bring up salary in the group interview is that only one of the four is the person I would eventually report to (CFO) and one or more of the other three might earn less than the range I want??

Comment: Does **group interview** mean that you are the only interviewee and there are many interviewers ?

Comment: I've edited the question to hopefully make it more clear.  Generally, a "group interview" is one where more than one candidate is interviewed at the same time.  A "panel interview" is one where multiple interviewers interview a single candidate at the same time.  Based on your 6 April clarification, it sounds like you are attending a panel interview not a group interview so I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Nothing wrong with bringing up that you'd like to discuss the topic privately with the relevant individual(s) after the group portion has concluded.

Answer (score 7):

My recommendation is to wait until you get an offer.  That way, you know they are interested in you.  If you talk salary too early in the process, you can disqualify yourself.

Your range and their range already meet at 60K, so you are not that far off.  In many cases a company will be willing to go over their budgeted amount for the right candidate.  Do your homework and understand what you can offer them that nobody else can.  Always be selling your abilities!

As always, be sure you are emphasizing your "value" so that when it comes time to talk money, you are not on the defensive.

Comment: I would recommend the opposite. Talk about salary as early as possible and don't waste your time on companies that will low-ball you regardless of how much they seem interested in you.

Answer (score 6):

Group settings are not a great place to discuss salary. Most interviews will also include some private time with a recruiter or hiring manager, you can bring up there or follow up by phone or e-mail.

If they bring it up during the group session and try to turn it into an auction ("who here is willing to work for the least salary"), I would just walk away. You don't want to work for a company like this.

Comment: *I* am being interviewed by four (4) people, this is a common interview format. Only good thing is it's the 2nd interview and things seem to be going well so far, I am trying to be prepared. Thank you, :) p